# Normalization Factor divide or multiply

Tags: normalization

If I want to normalize some data using a median normalization or trimmed mean normalization, do I multiply or divide my data by the normalization factors? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you define "Normalization Factor".

The goal of normalization is for all of your data to have the same scale, such as the same median or trimmed mean.

So if your "normalization factor" is a trimmed mean, you would divide, as this would make all of your trimmed means equal to 1.